# Key value coding-compliant error while fetching

Tags: swift, core-data

I like to move the row to `bottom` of the `table` and `persist` it that is I like it to see my changes when I come to my screen again, if the `eventStatus == 1 0r 2`. I did the following but the rows are not moving

```
        if eventSegCtrl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
        myEventCell.eventLabel.text = self.eventScheduleOnc[indexPath.row].eventNameOnc
        let eventDesc = self.eventScheduleOnc[indexPath.row].eventDecOnc
            let eventStatus = eventDesc?.eventStatus

           if eventStatus == 1 {
                myEventCell.eventLabel.textColor = UIColor.green
                do
                {
            //Create fetch request with NSSortDescriptor
                    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "EventScheduleOnc")
                    let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "indexOnc", ascending: true)
                    request.sortDescriptors = [sort]

             //   Acess the last objects index
                    let lastRowIndex = eventTitleOnc.count - 1
                    print(lastRowIndex)
                    request.setValue(lastRowIndex, forKey: "indexOnc")

              // Save it to core data
                   try context.save()
                _ = try context.execute(request)

                }
                catch{}
        }
```

I am getting this following error

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]:
>   this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key indexOnc.'

Comment: The error means that the entities in `request` do not have a property named `indexOnc`.

Comment: @rmaddy, but I have that attribute indexOnc http://imgur.com/5wrAobQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to set a value on your `NSFetchRequest`, which isn't done, in this line: `request.setValue(lastRowIndex, forKey: "indexOnc")`. The request won't have the key for one of your properties. Not sure what you're trying to do with it.